# How to authenticate user/password of a Google account on a standalone/desktop application in java

Tags: java, authentication, google-openid, google-oauth

I want to authenticate username/password of google account. So enters the user name and password in a form than i need to verify those credentials using java google api. The Google service on application is already authenticated by using oauth for standalone application which is using service account and private key file.  But need to verify the user give him access to the application.
currently i am using service.setUserCredentials of docsService which do not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is a exemple in the google api java library https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#installed_applications

Comment: This do not validate username and password. I have already authorize services to work using impersonate user and google app service account credentials. But want to validate user/password(will in the company domain) to give user access to my application.

Comment: It's not how it works. Google credential information shouldn't be comunicated to a third party. So you need to use oauth authentication.

Comment: What about an app that just want to login many users to change something like google drive permisions? How can you do it without having to login manually with oauth?